# spring mvc 3 with hibernate (and hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I've a problem setting up spring mvc 3 and hibernate with the auto dll
this is my folder structure:
[image: Folder structure]

**And these are my libraries:**

[image: Libraries]

**AbstractUser**

```
package org.andreadorigo.abstracts;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

/**
 * Generic user
 * @author andreadorigo
 *
 */

public abstract class AbstractUser {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    @Column(name="email")
    public String email;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 6, max = 14)
    @Column(name="password")
    public String password;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public AbstractUser() {
        super();
    }


    //Getters and setters
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }



}
```

**CustomerUser**

```
package org.andreadorigo.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.andreadorigo.abstracts.AbstractUser;

@Entity
@Table(name="customerUser")
public class CustomerUser extends AbstractUser{

}
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="org.andreadorigo" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property
            name="persistenceUnitName"
            value="jtdb" />

        <property
            name="dataSource"
            ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">

        <property
            name="showSql"
            value="true" />

        <property
            name="generateDdl"
            value="true" />

        <property
            name="databasePlatform"
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="CustomerUser">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>org.andreadorigo.entities.CustomerUser</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

But when I run jboss 7 I get these warnings/errors:

```
15:48:57,442 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean in Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/orm/jpa/AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean (Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    15:48:58,322 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
15:48:59,172 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean in Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean (Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader)

15:48:59,614 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-2) Monitoring jndi:/default-host/GenericProject/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
15:49:00,295 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean in Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/orm/jpa/AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean (Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    15:49:00,405 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /GenericProject
15:49:01,010 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean in Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean (Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader)

15:49:01,271 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean in Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/orm/jpa/AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean (Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader)

15:49:01,529 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean in Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean (Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader)

15:49:01,778 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-3) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
15:49:01,795 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean in Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/orm/jpa/AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean (Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader)

15:49:02,061 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean in Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean (Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
15:49:02,310 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-3) Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@55e3c942: defining beans [registerController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,viewResolver,entityManagerFactory]; root of factory hierarchy
15:49:02,374 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean in Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/orm/jpa/AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean (Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    15:49:02,749 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean in Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean (Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
15:49:03,126 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean in Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/orm/jpa/AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean (Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    15:49:03,505 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean in Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean (Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader)

15:49:03,839 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-3) Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@55e3c942: defining beans [registerController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,viewResolver,entityManagerFactory]; root of factory hierarchy
15:49:03,875 ERROR [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-3) Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0' threw an exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronization

15:49:04,031 ERROR [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-3) Destroy method on bean with name '(inner bean)' threw an exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronization


15:49:04,182 ERROR [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-3) Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0' threw an exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronization
    15:49:04,381 ERROR [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-3) Destroy method on bean with name 'registerController' threw an exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronization

15:49:04,530 ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (MSC service thread 1-3) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] for bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean from [Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] for bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean from [Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

15:49:04,868 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SpringTest]] (MSC service thread 1-3) StandardWrapper.Throwable: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] for bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean from [Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] for bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean from [Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader]


15:49:05,194 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SpringTest]] (MSC service thread 1-3) Servlet /SpringTest threw load() exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean from [Module "deployment.SpringTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 things wrong here

1. You are mixing spring versions 3.0.3 and 3.1.1, never mix different spring versions (well actually that goes for all frameworks).
2. You are at least missing the spring-tx.jar and spring-aop.jar.

I strongly suggest using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) or [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org) for managing your dependencies, saves you a lot of headaches searching for jars around the internet.

Next to that make up your mind on what you want to use for configuration, you have your entitymanager configured through a hibernate.cfg.xml, spring context file and persistence.xml. Why? Remove at least the hibernate.cfg.xml and put the needed config in persistence.xml.

Comment: How can you see I'm useing different versions of spring?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions about maven, it was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the `spring-tx` jar from your classpath given this line

```
15:49:04,031 ERROR [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] 
(MSC service thread 1-3) Destroy method on bean with name '(inner bean)' 
threw an exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronization
```

You can get it [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx).

You actually seem to be missing much more than that.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
```

Get all the spring jars from the [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework).

Comment: Where can you see full list of missing classes?

Comment: @AndreaDorigo You can't tell they are missing until you run your application and it complains. An IDE will usually do this for you.